# Should AngularJS logic be placed in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, separation-of-concerns

I want to refactor code of which I post examples below. I am very new to AngularJS. Now when I saw the code, I was very curious about all the logic that is placed in the HTML code.

```
<p ng-show="countForm.count.$dirty && countForm.count.$error.min" class="error-message">

<button ng-click="step(2)" ng-show="data.step == 1 && countForm.count.$dirty" ng-disabled="countForm.$invalid" class="line-break">

<div ng-class="{selected: data.spreadChoice == 3}" ng-click="data.spreadChoice = 3; step(3)" ng-mouseover="data.preSpreadChoice = 3" ng-mouseout="data.preSpreadChoice = data.spreadChoice">

<div ng-show="data.step >= 2" class="step" ng-class="{active: data.step == 3, done: data.step > 3, left: data.preSpreadChoice == 1, right: data.preSpreadChoice == 3}" ng-scroll-here="data.step == 3">

<p ng-switch-when="false" class="large">[[data.emails.length]] von [[data.count]] – <span class="red">[[Math.max(0,data.count-data.emails.length)]]</span> Members</p>

<div ng-show="data.step >= 5 && data.multipleTeams"  class="step" ng-class="{done: data.step > 5, active: data.step == 5}" ng-scroll-here="data.step == 5">

<button class="small" ng-disabled="!unitsForm.$dirty || unitsForm.$invalid" ng-click="addUnit(data.nextTeam, data.nextTeamleaderEmail)">
```

Shouldn't the HTML rather contain classes or attributes and the *logic*  itself should be placed in JS files or JS code? Is this a good (or at least a common) way of developing AngularJS? Or should placing logic in HTML be avoided?

Comment: Since the functionality is there, it is clearly meant to be used. In practice you will want to avoid putting overly complex logic into attributes, but you won't get around putting logic in there completely. Your controllers will become very messy if you try.

Comment: That's Angular. Crazy stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you ask me:

1. Client side business logic sits in services that are injected into directives\controllers.
2. UI logic is suppose to be placed in the controllers.

Now about adding logic to the views, if we are talking about business logic then it's a **big no no**. Use a method on your controller that will evaluate stuff using the service.

If we are talking about `ng-if`/`ng-show` conditions then only if they are small and "readable" conditions I would add them to the view. When it's more than that, I move them to the controller for debugging issues and since I believe the HTML should be readable.

Answer (score 5):

Placing logic in HTML using directives in angular is a good way. You cannot take full advantage of angular without placing logic in HTML.

> Controllers should contain view logic, but shouldn’t actually reference the DOM (referencing the DOM should only be done through directives). <sup>[ref](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2013/07/angularjs-best-practices.html)</sup>

Two things to remember or the best practices for AngularJS are

> - Treat the scope as read-only in views
> - Treat the scope as write-only in controllers
>     <sup>[ref](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2013/07/angularjs-best-practices.html)</sup>

Since you are placing logic in HTML, if you treat it as read-only, you can check conditions or extract data using functions in scope, but the original data model isn't disturbed whatever you do in HTML.

Also tying dom elements to specific directives are the most powerful features of angular.

When you use a datepicker, in jQuery, you could do as follows:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

then in JS:

```
jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
    start:'today',
    end:'tomorrow',
    showTime:true
})
```

You can do this in angular way as follows

This way even when a designer or someone who reads HTML will be able to read what and even you can pass the options from the element's attributes itself.

```
<div date-picker start="today" end="tomorrow" show-time="true"></div>
```

AngularJS's importance itself is declarative syntax and can contain expressions as attribute values like you posted. That is not at all a bad practice. Indeed it is common and good practice all developers do. Using logic in HTML in angularjs saves a lot of code writing by ourselves. All the heavylifting is done by angular behind the scenes.

[**See some best practices about AngularJS**](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2013/07/angularjs-best-practices.html)